# Determining the static electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

This is from a practical problem.

> On the 2d plane, the potential is fixed to $U_0$ on the two half-lines of $(-\infty, -1) \cup (1,\infty )$. The problem is to solve the potential at an arbitrary point.

I am thinking of using some holomorphic transform to turn the boundary into some regular one, but have failed so far.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to “unfold” the half lines into two full, parallel lines at $x=-1$ and $x=1$. Your map will need to go as $\sqrt{x\mp1}$ for $x\to \pm1$.

The natural choice is $\frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin z$. Indeed, it converts the plane minus two half-line branch cuts into a strip.

Hope this helps.